# AWS Cognito's SMS Multi Factor Authentication returns invalid code or auth state

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement authentication built on `Cognito` using their Go `SDK`. I have been able to get basic `username/password` authentication to work, but when I add in 2-factor authentication using `SMS` I am getting stuck.

Steps to reproduce :

1. I create the user with a username/password and email verification
2. I validate the email address
3. I set the phone number and request a verification code
4. I verify the phone number
5. I enable 2-factor authentication (via SMS)
6. I try to sign in and receive the SMS_MFA challenge
7. I receive the code on my phone and call AdminRespondToAuthChallenge

Problem, I receive an `error` :

```
CodeMismatchException: Invalid code or auth state for the user.
status code: 400, request id: 1513894e-8efa-11e8-a8f8-97e5e083c03b
```

The SMS verification code is certainly correct, so it seems that it must be something to do with the auth state.

The calls to Cognito look like this:

```
c.cip.SignUp(&cognitoidentityprovider.SignUpInput{
        ClientId: aws.String(c.clientID),
        Username: aws.String(username),
        Password: aws.String(password),
        UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
            {
                Name:  aws.String("email"),
                Value: aws.String(email),
            },
            {
                Name:  aws.String("name"),
                Value: aws.String(fullName),
            },
        },
    })

c.cip.ConfirmSignUp(&cognitoidentityprovider.ConfirmSignUpInput{
    ClientId:         aws.String(c.clientID),
    Username:         aws.String(username),
    ConfirmationCode: aws.String(code),
})


//Add the phone number
c.cip.AdminUpdateUserAttributes(&cognitoidentityprovider.AdminUpdateUserAttributesInput{
            UserPoolId: aws.String(c.userPoolID),
            Username:   aws.String(username),
            UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
                {
                    Name:  aws.String("phone_number"),
                    Value: aws.String(phoneNumber),
                },
            },
        })

//Request a verification code
c.cip.GetUserAttributeVerificationCode(&cognitoidentityprovider.GetUserAttributeVerificationCodeInput{
    AccessToken:   aws.String(accessToken),
    AttributeName: aws.String("phone_number"),
})

//Verify the phone number
c.cip.VerifyUserAttribute(&cognitoidentityprovider.VerifyUserAttributeInput{
    AccessToken:   aws.String(accessToken),
    AttributeName: aws.String("phone_number"),
    Code:          aws.String(code),
})

//Enable SMS 2-factor auth c.cip.AdminSetUserSettings(&cognitoidentityprovider.AdminSetUserSettingsInput{
    UserPoolId: aws.String(c.userPoolID),
    Username:   aws.String(username),
    MFAOptions: []*cognitoidentityprovider.MFAOptionType{
        &cognitoidentityprovider.MFAOptionType{
            AttributeName:  aws.String("phone_number"),
            DeliveryMedium: aws.String("SMS"),
        },
    },
})

c.cip.AdminInitiateAuth(&cognitoidentityprovider.AdminInitiateAuthInput{
    ClientId:   aws.String(c.clientID),
    UserPoolId: aws.String(c.userPoolID),
    AuthFlow:   aws.String("ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"),
    AuthParameters: map[string]*string{
        "USERNAME": aws.String(username),
        "PASSWORD": aws.String(password),
    },
})

c.cip.AdminRespondToAuthChallenge(&cognitoidentityprovider.AdminRespondToAuthChallengeInput{
        ClientId:      aws.String(c.clientID),
        UserPoolId:    aws.String(c.userPoolID),
        ChallengeName: aws.String("SMS_MFA"),
        Session:       aws.String(session),
        ChallengeResponses: map[string]*string{
            "USERNAME":     aws.String(username),
            "SMS_MFA_CODE": aws.String(code),
        },
    })
```

Doing a GetUser call shows the current state of the user:

```
User = {
              Enabled: true,
              MFAOptions: [{
                  AttributeName: "phone_number",
                  DeliveryMedium: "SMS"
                }],
              PreferredMfaSetting: "SMS_MFA",
              UserAttributes: [
                {
                  Name: "sub",
                  Value: "bd2bb8bc-dfe6-4216-829c-5ae975ce24e5"
                },
                {
                  Name: "email_verified",
                  Value: "true"
                },
                {
                  Name: "name",
                  Value: "Ben Vogan"
                },
                {
                  Name: "phone_number_verified",
                  Value: "true"
                },
                {
                  Name: "phone_number",
                  Value: "<redacted>"
                },
                {
                  Name: "email",
                  Value: "<redacted>"
                }
              ],
              UserCreateDate: 2018-07-24 03:29:49 +0000 UTC,
              UserLastModifiedDate: 2018-07-24 04:19:51 +0000 UTC,
              UserMFASettingList: ["SMS_MFA"],
              UserStatus: "CONFIRMED",
              Username: "bd2bb8bc-dfe6-4216-829c-5ae975ce24e5"
            }
```

I do not know if there is a way to query the user's auth state so that I can verify that.

The AWS documentation and unhelpful errors are driving me insane so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Read somewhere that using the email as the username might make it work. Can you give it a try?

Comment: In the configuration of the user pool I have selected the radio button that requires usernames to be email address or phone number, and under that selected that usernames but be email addresses.  So I believe all usernames are email addresses in my case.

Comment: Hi did you find something ?

Comment: Nope haven't found a resolution and effectively put this on hold as it isn't critical at the moment.  Eventually I will try using a token based 2 factor authentication and see if that works.

Comment: Works for me when USERNAME = email but not when equals cognito Id.

Comment: The only thing I notice right off the bat is that you're converting statically typed strings to strings as well as types that are not. Could be one has to be passed as a []byte value rather than a string?

Comment: It's a small thing, but in your question, you didn't show the AWS responses. In the response to `AdminInitiateAuth`, is the challenge you receive back `SMS_MFA`? Its been awhile since I've worked with Cognito at this level. One other gotcha that I've hit before is that `SECRET_HASH` is required if your Cognito app has a secret enabled.

edit: I've successfully used this lib for the SRP auth flow in Go too: https://github.com/alexrudd/cognito-srp

Comment: Hey, I was using this with react native, I had to pass user.challengeName to `Auth.confirmSignIn` and it worked. The default value for `mfaType` is null in the method definition.

Comment: @Ben did you get a solution??

Answer (score 0):

Your questions seems ambiguous.

step 2 you are

2. I set the phone number and request a verification code
3. I verify the phone number

this is nothing but MFA in Cognito. if you have configured the pool correctly.

You cannot have both phone for login and MFA. that doesn't make sense.

but if you have phone for login, then Cognito will send SMS every time with code. password is only for email logins.

Comment: I don't see how the question is ambiguous.  Step 1 clearly indicates that I created the account with a username & password.  I do not have phone for login.  I obviously have to set the phone number to request an SMS verification code for MFA, which I do in step 2.  And yes it is nothing but MFA in Cognito, and it does not work.  Having used Cognito for a while now my feeling is that it isn't ready for production use and would strongly recommend anyone reading this not to use it.  Aside from random bugs like this, being unable to make a backup of a user pool is a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging and going through open issues in amplify/cognito js repos, I found out this solution.

After receiving the code as SMS, **do not trigger/call authenticate flow once again to send the SMS MFA code** which causes the code to be invalidated and after getting the error you might notice another SMS MFA code being send which is due to the last authenticate call done to send initial SMS MFA code.

Instead create another path or method in which you can use either `adminRespondToAuthChallenge` or `sendMFACode` provided the `Session` parameter must have a value of session from the last authenticate call.

I am using the JS package and not Go but the logic must be the same.
In my case, I had built REST API's which calls the authenticate function within a Lambda.

`authenticate` function is called after user submits email & password in frontend.

```js
    import { CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

    // inside authenticate lambda function
    const userData = {
       Username: user.email,
       Pool:     userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: ...,
      onFailure: ...,
      mfaRequired: (challengeName, challengeParameters) => {
        const { Session } = cognitoUser;
        if (payload.mfa === undefined) {
         // returns mfaRequired response to frontend
          resolve({mfaRequired: true, session: Session}) 
        }
      }
   })
```

`sendSMSMFA` Lambda function which is called after user enters the code into the frontend

```js
// inside sendSMSMFA function
const cognitoAdminUser = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
cognitoAdminUser.adminRespondToAuthChallenge({
 UserPoolId: user_pool_id,
 ClientId: client_id,
 ChallengeName: 'SMS_MFA',
 Session: payload.session,
 ChallengeResponses: {
   SMS_MFA_CODE: payload.mfaCode,
   USERNAME: payload.email
  },
 }, (err, data) => {
   if (err) {
    console.log('error responding to auth challenge', err);
    reject(err);
   } else {
      console.log('Successfully responded to auth challenge', data);
      const idToken = data.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
      const AccessToken = data.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
      const refreshToken = data.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken;
      resolve({token: idToken, access: AccessToken, refresh: refreshToken})
    }
   })
```

Somewhere in the open issues, I read about a feature request which specifically asks for a function which verifies SMS MFA code and returns tokens but until that time comes, I think this is the clunky method to do it.

For anyone who wonders about why this isn't happening when using TOTP software token mehod is because the MFA code clock is separate of that of the cognito clock and thus there will always be a sync there even if codes are send in different `authenticate` calls but SMS MFA is really dependent on **session id**.